# Error initializing docker MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, docker

I was using the following script mounted on `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js` to initialize my `MongoDB 5.0`DDBB on `Docker`:

```
db.auth("admin", "MyPassw0rd_123");
db = db.getSiblingDB("RecipientService");
db.createCollection('RecipientAggregate');
db.createUser({
    user: "wfuser",
    pwd: "MyPassw0rd_",
    roles: [{
            role: "readWrite",
            db: "RecipientService"
        }
    ]
});
```

However, it doesn't seems to work anymore with `MongoDB 6.0`, I'm getting the following message in DDBB logs:

```
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

I can't find the right way to do it. I know the old mongo shell was deprecated in this version in favor of `mongosh`, maybe the syntax is not valid anymore, but I'm unable to find any advice after reading tons of docs.

Any clue about **how to init a MongoDB 6.0 DDBB on Docker**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to explicitly call `db.auth()` in your initialization script; if I remove the `db.auth()` line from your initialization script so that I have:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("RecipientService");
db.createCollection('RecipientAggregate');
db.createUser({
    user: "wfuser",
    pwd: "MyPassw0rd_",
    roles: [{
            role: "readWrite",
            db: "RecipientService"
        }
    ]
});
```

And I place this in `initdb.d/init-mongo.js`, and then start up Mongo with the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

It all seems to work correctly: once Mongo is up, I can connect and verify that the `RecipientService` database has been created:

```
$ docker-compose exec mongo mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 639692e63b75a4305eb53c47
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.1
Using MongoDB:          6.0.3
Using Mongosh:          1.6.1

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

test> use admin
switched to db admin
admin> db.auth('root', 'example')
{ ok: 1 }
admin> show dbs
RecipientService    8.00 KiB
admin             100.00 KiB
config             60.00 KiB
local              72.00 KiB
```

Comment: Thanks. Removing the db.auth() call made the trick.